# Django - (Hidden field order) The inline foreign key did not match the parent instance primary key

Tags: python, django

Other similar questions did not resolve my issue.

I'm getting the error message:

**(Hidden field order) The inline foreign key did not match the parent instance primary key.**

when trying to save from an edit form (ie already existing data). I have another method for in my view for saving new data.

my views.py:

```
def order_edit(request, order_id):
if request.POST:
    form = OrderForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        order = form.save(commit=False)
        drink_formset = DrinkFormSet(request.POST, instance=order)
        if drink_formset.is_valid():
            OrderService.save_order(order, drink_formset)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('coffee:dashboard'))
else:
    order = OrderService.load_order(order_id, request)
    form = OrderForm(instance=order)
    drink_formset = DrinkFormSet(instance=order)
return render(request, 'coffee/order_edit.html', {
    'form': form,
    'drink_formset': drink_formset,
    })
```

I have this defined in my forms.py:

```
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['description_text', ]


class DrinkForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Drink
        fields = ['type_of_drink']

    DrinkFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
        Order,
        Drink,
        form=DrinkForm,
        can_delete=False,
        extra=10)
```

This is my models.py:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    description_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateTimeField('date made')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description_text

    def was_recent(self):
        return self.date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    was_recent.admin_order_field = 'date'
    was_recent.boolean = True
    was_recent.short_description = 'Recent?'


class Drink(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order,)
    type_of_drink = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    placed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.type_of_drink
```

Any help is appreciated. I have been stuck on this for 2+ hours, getting frustrated :).

Comment: Can you please post your `Order` and `Drink` models?

Comment: updated. Thanks for looking.